# Flutter crash ADB on chromebook, no devices

Tags: android, flutter, adb, google-chrome-os, chromebook

After done all the installation of flutter on a chromebook with dev mode On (Asus C423NA) from here : https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/chromeos, I wanted to give it a try but unfortunately, as soon as i want to start or check device with `flutter devices` it crash adb.

If i restart the Adb connection to the android container of chromebook using `adb connect 100.115.92.2:5555` for the second time, the chromebook crash and reboot.

You can see all the command line in this image : 
[image]

Anyone has an idea on how can i make flutter run with android container ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a bug report with this issue. The bug got worse in Chrome OS 78, where the system crashes entirely now. Please star and follow the bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1000696

Comment: Did not thought about bug report ! Good (or not :D) to know that i'm not the only one ! On which device are you ? I feel like that anything apart from pixel is not working with flutter

Comment: I develop Android on a Pixelbook.

Comment: and flutter has the same problem on it ?!? I did not expect that

Comment: `adb connect 100.115.92.2:5555` is the way to connect to the Chrome OS Android container, which doesn't have anything to do with Flutter. It's the same for any Android app development.